# Array size problem while testing mergesort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I have to test Mergesort with different sizes of data. The problem I encounter is that if the array of ints is around the size of 5000000 my code is crashing but without giving an error. I calculated the amount of space the array would take and if I'm not wrong this would be about 0,02 GB and my RAM is 8GB. I also searched if there is a max size for an array and didnt find anything useful. So where is the problem?

```
     /* C program for Merge Sort */
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 2000000
int arr[MAX];

// Merges two subarrays of arr[].
// First subarray is arr[l..m]    
// Second subarray is arr[m+1..r]
void merge(int l, int m, int r)
{
int i, j, k;
int n1 = m - l + 1;
int n2 =  r - m;

/* create temp arrays */
int L[n1], R[n2];

/* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    L[i] = arr[l + i];
for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

/* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray
j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray
k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray
while (i < n1 && j < n2)
{
    if (L[i] <= R[j])
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}

/* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there
   are any */
while (i < n1)
{
    arr[k] = L[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}

/* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there
   are any */
while (j < n2)
{
    arr[k] = R[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}
}

/* l is for left index and r is right index of the
sub-array of arr to be sorted */
void mergeSort(int l, int r)
{
if (l < r)
{
    // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for
    // large l and h
    int m = l+(r-l)/2;

    // Sort first and second halves
    mergeSort(l, m);
    mergeSort(m+1, r);

    merge(l, m, r);
}
}

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Function to print an array */
void printArray()
{
int i;
for (i=0; i < MAX; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
printf("\n");
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
for (int var = 0; var < MAX; ++var) {
    arr[var] = rand() % 100;
}
clock_t t1, t2;
//printf("Given array is \n");
// printArray();
t1 = clock();
mergeSort(0, MAX - 1);
t2 = clock();
printf("\nSorted array is \n");
printArray();
float timetaken = t2 - t1;
timetaken /= CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Time spend:  %f\n", timetaken);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use local temp space for this. Non-in-place merge sort requires 2N space. You can make that happen by declaring *another* N-sized variable static (alongside `arr`), using that for temp storage. That avoids the stack-hungry problems you're having now while simultaneously avoiding the cost of dynamic memory management.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage (or better, both)  Names like 'l' 'm' 'r' 'n1' 'n2'  etc are meaningless, even in the current context.  2) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces  3) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line. 4) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: Following up on WhozCraig's comment, look at [wiki merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) for examples that use a one time allocated working array. Also top down merge sort is mostly used for learning. Most implementations of merge sort in libraries are variations of bottom up merge sort (wiki explains these as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in

> ```
> void merge(int l, int m, int r)
> {
> int i, j, k;
> int n1 = m - l + 1;
> int n2 =  r - m;
>
> /* create temp arrays */
> int L[n1], R[n2];
> ...
> ```

Probably L and R are too large to be placed in the stack, the size of the stack is limited, do `ulimit-a` to see the limit.

If this is the reason you will have to allocate them in the heap (*malloc*), and don't forget after to free them ;-)

---

When you need a big array whose size if a constant (this is not the case here) and the function using it is not directly nor indirectly recursive, you can use a static var, I mean for example : `void foo() { ... static int v[4096]; ... }` rather than `void foo() { ... int v[4096]; ... }`